# possible exceptions from IClientProxy.SendAsync (from Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

In SignalR v2, I used code like this (below) to handle exceptions that happened when my connections failed. What is the equivalent in SignalR v3? Does `SendAsync` or `SendAsyncCore` throw some exception should connections fail or serialization fail?

```
private async void ManagerOnUserRemoved(UserDto userDto)
{
    try
    {
        await Context.Clients.All.MyFunc(userDto);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException) { }
    catch (AggregateException) { }
}
```

I didn't see any exceptions listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.client.hubconnectionextensions.sendasync?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Update: I have the same question for the calls from the client-side (to `InvokeCoreAsync` et al).

Answer (score 0):

In SignalR V3 use `HubException` to capture exceptions that contain sensitive information, such as connection information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.hubexception?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

```cs
private async void ManagerOnUserRemoved(UserDto userDto)
{
    try
    {
        await Context.Clients.All.MyFunc(userDto);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) { 
//Now check exceptions what you want by exception message or exception code
    }
}
```

With this code you can handle all exceptions, or you can do this:

```cs
 hubConnection.Error += ex => Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
```

I think it will be help